# Need help in obtaining the longest harmonious array where the difference between max and min values are 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, hashmap, min

I've adapted the following question, instead of displaying the length.  I want to actually output the array.

We define a harmounious array as an array where the difference between its maximum value and its minimum value is exactly 1.
Now, given an integer array, you need to find the length of its longest harmonious subsequence among all its possible subsequences.  **(I am trying to find the actual array)**

Example 1:
Input: [1,3,2,2,5,2,3,7]
Output: 5
Explanation: The longest harmonious subsequence is [3,2,2,2,3].

I've written the following code but the values I am pushing into vals is incorrect.  I need help finding out how to correct it.

```
const findLHS = (nums) => {
    const hash = new Map()
    let vals = []
    let min = nums[0], max = nums[0]
    for (let num of nums) {
        //logic for finding min and max in range is flawed
        min = min + max === 1 ? Math.min(min, num) : min
        max = max - min === 1 ? Math.max(max, num) : max
        hash.set(num, (hash.get(num) || 0) + 1)
        console.log(max);
    }

    //logic is flawed below
    for (let key of nums) {
        // if (hash.has(key + 1) && hash.has(key + 1) <= max) {
        //     vals.push(hash.get(key + 1))
        // }
        if (hash.has(key) === min || hash.has(key) === max) {
            vals.push(min) || vals.push(max)
        }
    }
    return vals
}
```

The test cases, and what I believe should be returned:

```
console.log(findLHS([1, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7]))//5 [3,2,2,2,3]
console.log(findLHS([1, 2, 3, 4])) //2 [1,2]
console.log(findLHS([1, 2, 2, 1])) //4 [1,2,2,1]
```

Comment: Just to be sure of the requirement - are you saying that the phrase "longest harmonious subsequence" means "any collection of elements, even if not immediately adjacent"? I would read "subsequence" to mean "elements that are immediately adjacent". With that definition, I would take the answer to your first case to be [3, 2, 2]  not [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]. Which should it be?

Comment: What are the constraints (size of the array, range of values)?

Comment: I only have the output for the first one based on the question I derived the problem from the only constraint is that the max and min should be no more than 1, so whatever is in nums should be output based on that condition.  That will be the size of the array.  e.g first case should be `[3,2,2,2,3]` and correct they don't have to be adjacent.

Comment: `[1,2,3,4]` has several harmonious arrays tied for the same length.

Comment: When the length was asked for in the original problem, the output was 2; meaning two items in the array.  There can only be one min or max that is one away from the other, they would have to be structured in that manner to only output the first viable array based on the order the min and max are assigned.  So in this case our max should be two, and min one.  Therefore resulting in just [1,2] being our answer.  At least that is what I gleaned from the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take.  Using [1, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7] as an example...

- Stage 1: Create a Map which counts the number of values.  Eg, 1=>1, 3=>2, 2=>3, 5=>1, 7=>1
- Stage 2: Find the greatest total between two consecutive values.  Eg, 1's are seen 1x, 2's are seen 3x so between 1's and 2's, there are a total of 4 values.  Next, 3's are seen 2x, but there is no 4's in the array, so move to the next Map element.  So, 2's are seen 3x and 3's are seen 2x for a total of 5 values.  Etc.
- Stage 3: Finally, walk the original array pulling out the values.  Now that we know that for an array value of 2, that there are a total of 5 values of 2's and 3's, look through the array for 2's and 3's.

```js
function findLHS( arr ) {

  // Count the number of occurrences of each value in the array...
  let count = new Map();
  arr.forEach( v => {
    count.set( v, ( count.get( v ) || 0 ) + 1 );
  } );
  
  // Now, find the largest count of two consecutive numbers.
  let maxKey;
  let maxCount = -1;
  count.forEach( ( val, key ) => {
    if ( count.get( key + 1 ) ) {
      let total = val + count.get( key + 1 );
      if ( maxCount < total ) {
        maxKey = key;
        maxCount = total;
      }
    }
  } );
  
  // Finally, return the result.
  if ( maxCount == -1 ) {
    return [];
  } 
  
  return arr.reduce( ( acc, val) => {
    if ( val == maxKey || val == maxKey + 1 ) {
      acc.push( val );
    }
    return acc
  }, [] );
    
}

console.log( findLHS( [ 1, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7] ) ); 
console.log( findLHS( [ 1, 2, 3, 4] ) );
console.log( findLHS( [ 1, 2, 2, 1 ] ) );
```

Hope this helps...